# PS4 won't enter safe mode

Tags: ps4

I just bought my PS4 and very quickly realized that 500GB is not going to be enough. So I decided to upgrade to a 2TB hdd. I am using a Nyko power bank to hold the hdd. When trying to boot the PS4 into safe mode, so I can initialize the PS4, it simply won't. I have tried multiple times with different solutions but with the same outcome. The thing is, when I put the 500GB hdd back in, it boots up into safe mode with no problems. Does anyone have a solution? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you uploaded the firmware to the new hard drive? Essentially you aren't booting up from anything just putting an empty hard drive in. If i understand this correctly

Comment: I know that there is size limit to the HDD for the PS4 to enter certain modes, like rest. I do believe that it is 2 TB for that one specifically. I would not be surprised if it was the same for safe mode. The PS4 was not designed to support that size HDD initially, rumors are that Sony is working on a solution though

Comment: No, I've done my research and anything bigger than 2tb is where you can't use rest mode. 2tb is just fine but I think the hdd may be defective which is what I'm looking into now

Answer (score 2):

See if this [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDfG7x2LkkQ) is able to help you access recover mode.

**Instructions**:

- Completely turn off the PS4 (do not put it on stand-by mode)
- Press and hold down the power button for around 10 seconds. The
  console will beep twice, around 5 seconds apart.
- On the second
  beep, let go of the power button and the PS4 will enter safe mode.
- Connect a DualShock 4 controller via the USB port and press
  the PS button. You can then use the controller to select the
  appropriate mode.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen to my son's PS4. It wouldn't access safe mode, no matter how I tried: standard method, power cycle, alternate methods (some have waited for 3 beeps), etc.

Here's what worked: replacing the hard drive with a brand new one. As soon as I swapped it, I was able to access it with no issues. Reinstalled the latest firmware and voila: PS4 is back!

Hope this helps.

You can get a hard drive pretty much anywhere. Just make sure it fits and don't go crazy with the storage, some PS4's can only handle up to 2TB.

Comment: Considering how terrible is the PS4 for handling SATA Drives, this is something that might work when the internal drive is corrupted (partitions and/or drive firmware).

Answer (score 0):

I kept holding down the power button hoping it would beep in 7 seconds but it wouldn't. It kept double beeping at 12 seconds. So I turned it off. then when powering on I held the power button for 7 seconds then released it for a second and then held it for 7 seconds then it beeped once and then I plugged in the controller and pressed the ps button. The grey screen came up but it took a minute for the text to show up. Once I finally got into safe mode I rebuilt the database and boom. It works again.